# Metro style apps horizontal scrolling using mousewheel

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

Hi i was trying to make a proof of concept for my metro style app.
this is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height: 600px">
    <div id="wrapper" style="width:10000px">
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Left Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Middle Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
     <div class="child" style="float: left; width: 200px; border-style: solid;">Right Stuff</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
        $(".child").wrap("<td></td>");

        document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function (event) {
            $('body').scrollLeft($('body').scrollLeft() - event.wheelDelta);
        };
    });
</script>
```

The mousewheel event is working fine in IE10 (windows 8), so i created a html5 javascript metro style application containing just 2 files: default.html file with the above code and the jquery.min.js file.

When running the application i had the same display but horizontal scrolling was not working when using mousewheel like it worked in ie 10.
Note: mousewheel event is captured in Metro (put a breakpoint on this row "$('body').scrollLeft($('body').scrollLeft() - event.wheelDelta);" but this is not scrolling.

What is the problem with metro and is there any other way to make the horizontal scrolling.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Use .win-horizontal instead of your #wrapper. This worked for me.

Found the answer at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/3b4e4ffa-3d27-4d34-810b-03311fac03e8

Thank you Juliana Peña.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with the code you have showing all I did was add event.preventDefault(); to stop the default vertical scrolling.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#wrapper").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
    $(".child").wrap("<td></td>");

    document.documentElement.onmousewheel = function (event) {
        $('body').scrollLeft($('body').scrollLeft() - event.wheelDelta);
        event.preventDefault();
    };
});
```